# How can you remotely login to a remote computer using C#?

Tags: c#, remote-access

I'm trying to write a small command line application with C# that will prompt for a username and a password that will be used to login to several remote computers that are sitting on the same network/domain and start a local session.

I've tried connecting to a remote computer and to query the remote PC's operating system info with the following code:

```
ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();

ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\REMOTE_COMPUTER_NAME");
scope.Connect();

ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject m in queryCollection)
{
    // Display the remote computer information
    Console.WriteLine("Computer Name : {0}", m["csname"]);
    Console.WriteLine("Windows Directory : {0}", m["WindowsDirectory"]);
    Console.WriteLine("Operating System: {0}", m["Caption"]);
    Console.WriteLine("Version: {0}", m["Version"]);
    Console.WriteLine("Manufacturer : {0}", m["Manufacturer"]);
}
```

However, this only returns information on the local PC that I'm working on and not on the remote PC.

Am I overlooking something with this code? And is there an appropriate approach to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: What do you mean by "remotely login"? Do you want to start a local session? Remote desktop? SMB share access?

Comment: @Dai start a local session.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have remote machine right now to give you the working example, but you can try this. [advapi32.logonuser](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32.logonuser)

Example:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
public static extern bool LogonUser(string name, string domain, string pass, 
int logType, int logpv, out IntPtr pht);

IntPtr ptr;
// LogonUser("username", "remotemachine", "password", 2, 0, out ptr);
LogonUser("username", "remotemachine", "password", 9, 0, out ptr);
WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(ptr);
var impersonationContext = windowsIdentity.Impersonate();

// your code goes here...

impersonationContext.Undo();
```

> This logon type allows the caller to clone its current token and
>   specify new credentials for outbound connections. The new logon
>   session has the same local identifier but uses different credentials
>   for other network connections.  NOTE: This logon type is supported
>   only by the LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50 logon provider. NOTE: Windows NT:
>   This value is not supported.

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32.logonuser

Edit

Give it a try [cassia](https://code.google.com/p/cassia/)

```
ITerminalServicesManager manager = new TerminalServicesManager();
using (ITerminalServer server = manager.GetRemoteServer("servername"))
{
    server.Open();
    foreach (ITerminalServicesSession session in server.GetSessions())
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Hi there, " + session.UserAccount + " on session " + session.SessionId);
        Console.WriteLine("It looks like you logged on at " + session.LoginTime +
                            " and are now " + session.ConnectionState);
    }
}
```

Comment: This throws a `System.ArgumentException` of `Token cannot be zero`. Upon debugging it's showing that `ptr` is 0 so does that mean that the `LogonUser(...)` unsuccessfully logon?

Comment: yep. If ptr is zero, then logon failed.

Comment: So I downloaded the cassia distribution and scanned through the documentation and couldn't find anthing that would allow for me to log in (aka start a local session) on a remote computer. I found methods to Logoff and to kill processes, but nothing dealing with logging in.

Comment: @aus_lacy can you try my first suggestion only change logon type from 2 to 9 and let me know if it works.

Comment: Changing the `int dwLogonType` from 2 to 9 got me past the `Token cannot be zero` exception, but now it doesn't matter what credentials (username or password) I give it. It will always return a non-zero which according to the documentation signifies success.

Comment: It means that you are logged in to remote server as specified user.

Comment: But I shouldn't be able to log in using invalid credentials which is what I provided it with and it consistently returned a non-zero.

Comment: Yes it returns non-zero value, but if you will try to for example create new file, then it will throw an exception.

Comment: For example try this: File.WriteAllText(@"\\yournetworkpath\c$\file.txt", "content");

Comment: The comment on PInvoke says: "*The LogonUser function attempts to log a user on to the local computer. The local computer is the computer from which LogonUser was called. **You cannot use LogonUser to log on to a remote computer**.*"

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ConnectionOptions and pass it to the ManagementScope

```
    public void GetSystemInformation(string _yourDomain, string _hostName, string _userName, SecureString _password)
    {
        ManagementScope Scope = null;
        string computerName = _hostName;
        string userName = _userName;
        SecureString password = _password;
        ManagementObjectCollection collection = null;

        try
        {
            SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
            //string query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration" + " WHERE IPEnabled = 'TRUE'";

            var options = new ConnectionOptions
            {
                  EnablePrivileges = false,
                  Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate,
                  Username = _userName,
                  SecurePassword = _password,
                  Authority = "ntlmdomain:" + _yourDomain
            };
            Scope.Options = options;
            Scope.Connect();

            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Scope, query);
            collection = searcher.Get();

           //Do something with the collection
        }
        catch (ManagementException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private static SecureString CreateSecuredString(string pw)
    {
        var secureString = new SecureString();

        foreach (var c in pw)
        {
            secureString.AppendChar(c);
        }

        return secureString;
    }
```

You might have to try some different stats with the variables *EnablePrivileges* and *Impersonation*

**edit:**

If you want to get your information from your pc (local) than you dont have to pass the options to the scope.

Comment: I tried the various `ConnectionOptions` configurations without success. My goal is to use my current credentials to remote login, which is why I didn't pass an `options` parameter to the `ManagementScope`. If I don't pass it the `options` it only returns info on the local machine I am working on despite giving it the computer name of the remote PC and when I give it `options` it throws an `invalid parameter` exception when I try to connect after creating the `ManagementScope`.

Comment: Just edited it. Did you already try it with the property "Authority"? If so than be shure you used  "**ntlmdomain**:yourdomain", because there is a spelling mistake at msdn

Comment: Yes I set the `Authority` properly with the same `invalid parameter` result. According to MSDN if I want to use the same credentials as the ones I am logged in with, then I don't need an options parameter.